# Localize an MFC-based DLL?

Tags: c++, mfc, localization

I use Visual C++ 2008 to create a DLL which is statically linked with MFC. Now I need to localize the DLL so that it supports both English and German. I read the article at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6h91d9w and it says to use localized MFC resources, one needs:

> To cause your application to use these RC files instead of the files
>   located in MFC\INCLUDE, add a /IC:\PROGRAM FILES\MICROSOFT VISUAL
>   STUDIO .NET 2003\VC7\MFC\INCLUDE\L.DEU to your RC command line (this
>   is just an example; you would need to substitute your locale of choice
>   as well as the directory into which you installed Visual C++).

Then how to do that in the Visual Studio environment, since I do not call the RC command line directly when compiling the project.

Thanks

Alan

Answer (score 1):

You open the project properties in Visual Studio (one way is to right click on the project in solution explorer, properties is on the bottom) In the common properties there is a Resources section, in this there is a Command line section which allows you to add arbitrary strings which will get added to the command line.

Comment: THank you very much. If I already have a compiled resource DLL and want to add the MFC localized resources into it, then how to do that?

Comment: The way it is normally done is to build multiple resource DLLs, one per language and then the application selects the DLL to load when it starts or, I suppose, the installer installs the DLL for the correct language. So you would have multiple builds defined, and select the German include file in the German build only.